# Setting Visibility of Datagrid rows to Collapsed seems to break scrollbar?

Tags: c#, wpf, scroll, datagrid, visibility

I have a Datagrid containing items as List, one property in this custom list is a bool which determines visibility (the visibility can be toggled by a checkbox).

I have that working as this:

```
<Style x:Key="RowStyle" TargetType="DataGridRow">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=IsVisible}" Value="False">
            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
        </DataTrigger>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=IsVisible}" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
        </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

And my Datagrid is like:

```
<DataGrid Name="dataList" DataContext="{StaticResource DataViewSource}" ItemsSource="{Binding}" 
          ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource RowStyle}"
          ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
          ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
          AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
          CanUserAddRows="False" 
          CanUserDeleteRows="False" 
          IsReadOnly="True"
          CanUserReorderColumns="True" CanUserSortColumns="True"> ..etc
```

Assume I have 100 rows and when toggling the visibility, 80 of those rows are collapsed.

The issue is: the scrollbar doesn't seem to update when the visibility of items is changed. In appearance it will look as if those 80 rows are still visible (small drag bar) but when trying to scroll through the 20 items that are visible, it requires a lot more scrolling because the scrollbar is assuming that it's still having to scroll through 100 items or something.

Is there a way I can inform the scrollbar of visibility changes? Or should I handle the scroll event myself and remove the scrollbar from the datagrid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Datagrid uses something called row virtualization by default. When row virtualization is enabled, the scrollbar uses logical scoll units (items) instead of the real size.

Because your collection still contains all items, the scrollbar size does not change.

Solution:

Use the `Filter` event of the CollectionViewSource instead of binding to the Items viewmodel. [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.windows.data.collectionviewsource.filter(v=vs.110).aspx)